# How give selected action in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a created a single action in my nova resource and whenever I want to run the action, I have to click on the checkboxes and then I have to select the action in the action dropdown list.

As I have only one action in my resource , I want the action to be **selected by default** whenever I click on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the way Laravel Nova is implemented.

Alternatively, you could use a package like [pdmfc/nova-action-button](https://novapackages.com/packages/pdmfc/nova-action-button) which allows you to execute an action directly on your resource table view.